# can a conjunction be positively relevant to an event, if that event is independent of the two conjuncts taken separately.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm wondering whether if we take an event $A$ that is probabilistically independent of two further events $B$ and $C$, the conjunction $B∩C$ could ever be positively relevant to $A$. I think this is equivalent to asking if the following conditions can be satisfied:

$P(A|B)=P(A)$
$P(A|C)=P(A)$
$P(A|B∩C)>P(A|B)$

I've wrestled with it for a good while, and I can't seem to show either that these conditions can be satisfied or that they can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider flipping a coin twice.

Let $A$ be the event that the second coin flip has the same result as the first.

Let $B$ be the event that the first coin flip is heads

Let $C$ be the event that the second coin flip is heads

Then $P(A|B)=P(A|C)=P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$

But $P(A|B \cap C) =1$